# I have a problem loading large course package files into Moodle - I get an error saying the server responded with a status of 413

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, moodle, nginx-config

So my first thought was its a php config issue. I changed the php settings for the domain via Plesk to:
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M

I then checked the "General PHP Settings" for the server (also via Plesk) and changed the parameters in the php.ini file to
post_max_size = 2048M
upload_max_filesize = 2048M
This was in the '7.4.30 FPM application' Handler. I also checked the settings were the same in the '7.4.30 FastCGI application' Handler.

I then restarted the server and tried to load a large file into my Moodle system. I got a "Error connecting to the server" error.

I checked the "Files and Uploads setting in Moodle - it said "Site upload limit (2GB)" - all good!

In the browser debugger I could see that what I was actually getting was a 413 code error from an HTTP POST request generated by a php routine 'repository_ajax.php' - when I looked at this module it said it was part of the Moodle installation and that a given parameter would be blank if the file exceeded the Upload_max_filesize limit (which it didn't!) BUT the next line tested for 'blank' and threw the 413 error.

My next action was to check the server logs - I should have said this is a Cloud Server running Linux Ubuntu 20.4
The logs showed an nginx error "client intended to send too large body: 562992008 bytes" - which is the precise size of my file. So, I am comfortable that my problem is a server config issue with nginx and NOT a php config issue - which, after all is what the error message actually says.

My problem is I don't know how to change the nginx config - by using SSH Terminal I can see there is a file nginx.conf in /etc/nginx - but then I'm stuck - basically, I'm a Windows person and don't really know SSH OR nginx - can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

OK - I was having a bad day and suffering from brain fog! - I was loading another site into a domain on the server and needed to add "story.html" as a custom index files for the site - I opened Plesk, selected the domain then clicked "Hosting and DNS" settings and "Apache & nginx Settings" to add a custom value to the index files list (which I have done many times before) AND THERE IT WAS!!! Further down the page "nginx settings" including "Maximum allowed HTTP request body size. I set it to 2048Mb on the domain I was having problems with and problem solved.....
Duuuuhhhh